# Export Authnet ARB users to Paypal Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal, authorize.net

Is there any way to seamlessly export my Authnet ARB subscription users to Paypal recurring payments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There isn't. You don't have the credit card information to create the new subscriptions with.